# change specific class in whole WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Any idea how i can change specific class in whole WordPress theme
i tried many plugins already but none of them work ,The class exist in too many files it's gard to edit it in every file

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the class in custom css option?

Check here - https://wordpress.com/support/custom-design/editing-css/